# Giving a Spatial GEOGPOINT in BigQuery, How can we plot X points surrounded equally from the center point

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, spatial, looker

In BigQuery assume I have a GEOPOINT Datatype. Say for eg `ST_GEOGPOINT(-122, 37)` How can I find say 10 GEOGPOINTS that make the Outer Circle with the radius as 100 km.

The requirement is for a Looker Dashboard, where I have the GPS Data of Devices at the lowest level and we are tracking it's activity.

Now we will create an aggregated table at City Level as following data with

- City & Age Bucket as the Grain the table.
- Here we calculate an aggregated central GPS point of all Devices under the Activity Bucket using `ST_CENTROID_AGG` function in BigQuery

| city | Age Bucket | Central GEOGPOINT | # of Devices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texas, USA | 1 Day | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 100 |
| Texas, USA | 1 Week | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 10 |
| Texas, USA | 1 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 10 |
| Texas, USA | 2 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 10 |
| Texas, USA | 4 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 10 |
| Texas, USA | 6 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 10 |
| Texas, USA | 10 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(31, 99) | 100 |
| Florida, USA | 1 Day | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 100 |
| Florida, USA | 2 Week | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 10 |
| Florida, USA | 3 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 10 |
| Florida, USA | 5 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 10 |
| Florida, USA | 6 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 10 |
| Florida, USA | 9 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 10 |
| Florida, USA | 10 Month | ST_GEOGPOINT(27, 81) | 100 |

Here while plotting, the I would like to see all Florida being plotted at the central point with concentric circles around it.
For Texas, USA here it needs 6 points in the outside circle
For Florida, USA here it needs 7 points in the outside circle

How can we have a BigQuery function where I can get these GEOGPOINTS (either pre-calcualted in agg table or as a runtime function) to plot in a better way

I tired to play around the following article

https://towardsdatascience.com/spatial-binning-with-google-bigquery-d118afba6273

And could get some approximate cirlces, which will be looking oval due to how Lat & Long is shown in Map and get skewed at either north or south poles

```
--
-- Table Function to Generate Circular Points for an input (Will be Oval in Shape)
--
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION looker_iot_model.approx_circle_points(
  latitude FLOAT64, longitude FLOAT64, circle FLOAT64, points INTEGER)
AS (
SELECT
  seq,
  ST_GEOGPOINT(longitude + ((SIN(ACOS(-1)*seq/points))*circle/9), latitude + ((COS(ACOS(-1)*seq/points))*circle/10)) AS geo_point
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(-1*(points-1),(points-1),2)) as seq
);
```

Now If I run

1. For near equator, it looks as follows

`select * FROM looker_iot_model.approx_circle_points(37.7749, -122.4194, 12, 12)`

[image]

2. For near poles, it looks as follows

`select * FROM looker_iot_model.approx_circle_points(71, 42, 12, 12)`

[image]

Comment: Does ST_Buffer(central_point, 100*1000, 10/4) fits the bill? The second argument is radius (in meters), the  third one is number of points per quarter. It returns POLYGON with 10 vertices (that look like 11 due to first and last one repeated in POLYGON loop).

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Yes I tried this function and it shows a single GEOGRAPHY Shape with the requirement. Do you know what BigQuery function can be used to extract the points from this shape? Looks like it should be easy, but could not find a function.
Tried `SELECT seq, ST_POINTN(ST_Buffer(ST_GEOGPOINT(-122.4194, 37.7749), 100*1000, 10/4), seq) AS FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1,10)) seq` and it gives an error `The input is not a single LINESTRING`

Comment: Yeah, ST_PointN requires linestring input - you can get one from polygon using st_exteriorring(st_buffer(...)). But I think text manipulation is easier, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_Buffer(central_point, 100*1000, 10/4)` builds a polygonized loop around the central point. The second argument is radius (in meters), the third one is number of points per quarter. It returns POLYGON with 10 vertices (that look like 11 due to first and last one repeated in POLYGON loop)

To convert it to list of points we would need `ST_DumpPoints` that is not available in BigQuery, let's build poor-man version of it using text manipulation:

```
select st_geogfromtext(concat("POINT(", p, ")")) AS point
from unnest(split(
  trim(
    st_astext(st_buffer(ST_GEOGPOINT(-122, 37), 100e3,
                        num_seg_quarter_circle => 10/4)),
    "POLYGON()"),
  ",")) p with offset o
where o <> 0;
```

This builds a buffer, converts it to text, strips "polygon((..))" wrappings, splits the remaining points, and converts them back to geographies omitting the first point (that is repeated at the end of polygon definition).

[image]

Comment: Yes this works. I would say ST_DumpPoints should be an easier addition to the Google Spatial Function Stack. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Consider also below approach

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ST_GEOGPOINT(-122, 37) point, 10 points UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, ST_GEOGPOINT(-118, 34), 16
)
SELECT id, ST_UNION_AGG(ST_POINTN(ring, index)) outer_points,
  ANY_VALUE(point) point, ANY_VALUE(points) points
FROM your_table, 
UNNEST([ST_EXTERIORRING(ST_BUFFER(point, 100e3, num_seg_quarter_circle => points /4))]) ring,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, ST_NUMPOINTS(ring) - 1)) index
GROUP BY id
```

with  output

[image]

which ends up with below visualizations

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Mikhail Berlyant for the answer, We had implemented another approach in our project, which I wanted to share with the community, using the Maths approach mentioned in [Spatial Binning with BigQuery](https://towardsdatascience.com/spatial-binning-with-google-bigquery-d118afba6273)

Latitude and Longitude values are varied based on the below similar formula in ranked_point functions.

[image: Forumula]

```
--==============================================================================
--
-- BigQuery Scalar Function to Return the Aggregated & Shifted Circular Points
-- Parameters:
--   geo.point  - Original GEOGRAPHY coordinates
--   geo.seq    - Angular Point Sequence for the Circle | Numerator
--   geo.plots  - Number of Angular Points for the Circle | Denominator
--   zoom       - Zoom Level. Higher the value, More the Zoom into the Map
-- Return:
--   calc_geo_point - Calculated GEOGRAPHY coordinates
--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `looker_iot_model.ranked_point` (
  geo STRUCT<point GEOGRAPHY, seq INTEGER, plots INTEGER>, zoom INTEGER )
OPTIONS ( description="BigQuery Scalar Function to Return the Aggregated & Shifted Circular Points" )
AS
  (
  ST_GEOGPOINT(
    CASE
      -- longitude
      WHEN ST_X(geo.point) IS NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN geo.seq = 1 THEN ST_X(geo.point)
      WHEN geo.plots <= 12 THEN
        180/ACOS(-1)*
          (2*ACOS(-1)*
            (((ST_X(geo.point)*ACOS(-1)/180+ACOS(-1))/(2*ACOS(-1))*POW(2,zoom))  --tiled_x
              + SIN(2*ACOS(-1)*geo.seq/(geo.plots-1)))/   --shift_x
                POW(2,zoom)-ACOS(-1))
      WHEN geo.seq <= DIV(geo.plots,3)+1 THEN
        180/ACOS(-1)*
          (2*ACOS(-1)*
            (((ST_X(geo.point)*ACOS(-1)/180+ACOS(-1))/(2*ACOS(-1))*POW(2,zoom))  --tiled_x
              + SIN(2*ACOS(-1)*geo.seq/DIV(geo.plots,3)))/   --shift_x
                POW(2,zoom)-ACOS(-1))
      ELSE
        180/ACOS(-1)*
          (2*ACOS(-1)*
            (((ST_X(geo.point)*ACOS(-1)/180+ACOS(-1))/(2*ACOS(-1))*POW(2,zoom-1))  --tiled_x
              + SIN(2*ACOS(-1)*(geo.seq-DIV(geo.plots,3))/(geo.plots-DIV(geo.plots,3)-1)))/   --shift_x
                POW(2,zoom-1)-ACOS(-1))
    END,
    CASE
      -- latitude
      WHEN ST_Y(geo.point) IS NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN geo.seq = 1 THEN ST_Y(geo.point)
      WHEN geo.plots <= 12 THEN
        360/ACOS(-1)*
          (ATAN(EXP(ACOS(-1)-2*ACOS(-1)/
            POW(2,zoom)*
              ((POW(2,zoom)/(2*ACOS(-1))*(ACOS(-1)-SAFE.LN(TAN(ACOS(-1)/4 + (ST_Y(geo.point)/180*ACOS(-1))/2)))) --tiled_y
                + COS(2*ACOS(-1)*geo.seq/(geo.plots-1))) --shift_y
                  ))-ACOS(-1)/4)
      WHEN geo.seq <= DIV(geo.plots,3)+1 THEN
        360/ACOS(-1)*
          (ATAN(EXP(ACOS(-1)-2*ACOS(-1)/
            POW(2,zoom)*
              ((POW(2,zoom)/(2*ACOS(-1))*(ACOS(-1)-SAFE.LN(TAN(ACOS(-1)/4 + (ST_Y(geo.point)/180*ACOS(-1))/2)))) --tiled_y
                + COS(2*ACOS(-1)*geo.seq/DIV(geo.plots,3))) --shift_y
                  ))-ACOS(-1)/4)
      ELSE
        360/ACOS(-1)*
          (ATAN(EXP(ACOS(-1)-2*ACOS(-1)/
            POW(2,zoom-1)*
              ((POW(2,zoom-1)/(2*ACOS(-1))*(ACOS(-1)-SAFE.LN(TAN(ACOS(-1)/4 + (ST_Y(geo.point)/180*ACOS(-1))/2)))) --tiled_y
                + COS(2*ACOS(-1)*(geo.seq-DIV(geo.plots,3))/(geo.plots-DIV(geo.plots,3)-1))) --shift_y
                  ))-ACOS(-1)/4)
    END
    )
);
--
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now when you run the query, you will get concentric circles which you can use to visualise your metrics across various dimensions

```
WITH params AS
(
  SELECT
    STRUCT(ST_GEOGPOINT(-122.4194, 37.7749) AS point,
           48 AS plots) AS geo_data, 
           12 as Zoom
)
SELECT
  seq,
  looker_iot_model.ranked_point(
    STRUCT(geo_data.point AS point, seq AS seq, geo_data.plots AS plots), 
    zoom
  ) AS geo_point
FROM params
JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, geo_data.plots, 1)) AS seq;
```

[image: GeoViz]